# Linking C++ code to C in Borland C++ 3.1 compiler

Tags: c, linker-errors, borland-c++

Part of my FYP is to write code for a very old game(Wolfenstein-3D). It requires the use of the Borland C++ v3.1 compiler. This is the code I currently have but it's giving an error in the Borland compiler. Any ideas?

Error In Compiler:
[image: Error In Compiler]

Neuron.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus // only actually define the class if this is C++
class Neuron {
    public:
        void foo();
        int bar(int x, int y);
    };

#else   // C doesn't know about classes, just say it's a struct
    typedef struct Neuron Neuron;

#endif

// access functions
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define EXPORT_C extern "C"
#else
    #define EXPORT_C
#endif

EXPORT_C Neuron* NeuronNew(void);
EXPORT_C void NeuronDelete(Neuron* n);
EXPORT_C void NeuronFoo(Neuron* n);
EXPORT_C int NeuronBar(Neuron* n, int x, int y);
```

Neuron.cpp

```
#include "NEURON.h"

void Neuron::foo() {
}

int Neuron::bar(int x, int y) {
    return x+y;
}

EXPORT_C Neuron* NeuronNew(void) {
    return new Neuron();
}

EXPORT_C void NeuronDelete(Neuron* n) {
    delete n;
}

EXPORT_C void NeuronFoo(Neuron* n) {
    return n->foo();
}

EXPORT_C int NeuronBar(Neuron* n, int x, int y) {
    return n->bar(x, y);
}
```

Usage in C source file

```
#include "NEURON.h"
...

void GameLoop (void)
{
    ...
    Neuron* m = NeuronNew();

    NeuronFoo(m);
    NeuronDelete(m);

    ...
}
```

My assumption is that even though the compiler is a C++ compiler there's something 'new' in the C++ code that the compiler can't handle

Comment: You are not compiling any C++ code at all.  So it doesn't matter that it is a C++ compiler.  You only gave a typedef, the struct has to be defined *somewhere*.  We can't see it, the compiler couldn't either.

Comment: Interesting, how do you propose defining the struct in order to get the compiler to at least produce no errors. It's been a while since I've written C and trying an amendment to typedef struct Neuron{ int ans; }Neuron; didn't do anything. What's interesting is the code compiles and runs fine in CLion which is why I'm lead to believe the underlying issue is Borland.

Comment: Make sure you use `NeuronNew` and not `_Neuron_new` in the C file.

Comment: not sure if `__cplusplus` is defined token in old TC++ why bother with C? when you know you got C++. if you need to make the source compilable in C then do not use C++ otherwise you would need to code everything twice ... or add tons of defines making the code unreadable. Also how are you importing exporting the functions may be it is mangling problem as you are most likely linking. Also `*.C` implies `C` code and not `C++` !!!

Comment: @HansPassant, at least in current versions of GCC and Clang (back about a decade at least), you can forward-declare struct pointers without ever having to declare them in your headers. The actual definition only needs to be present where you are actually creating an "instance" of your struct (i.e. a variable, accessing a field, or taking its size to malloc/new it).

Comment: @Spektre , he's adding to Wolfenstein 3D, which was written in C. I don't think he has the time to rewrite the entire thing. And the extern "C" parts are exactly for that: Deactivate C++ name mangling to produce a C wrapper around the C++ code.

Comment: @uliwitness, Yeah being honest I'm shooting in the dark here. It's been nearly two years since I've had to explicitly handle pointers. The source code is in C, I'm just trying to see if I can write my Final Year Project code in C++ so I still use OOP. I can just write it in C but i'd really rather not

Answer (score 0):

The error message looks very much like the one you get from other compilers when they can't build the .cpp file for your class. It's not complaining about `NeuronNew`, but about `_Neuron_new` (note lowercase 'n' and extra underscore), so that's likely what Borland names the constructor/destructor?

Is it successfully compiling the .cpp and as C++? Is the file suffix mapping hooked up for those in the compiler? Have you added invalid code to the `#ifdef __cplusplus` line to verify that is *ever* defined, and not *always* defined (as 0 or 1)? Are you using the same case for all includes, file names and in the Makefile/project so they can be found?

Oh, have you tried doing:

```
typedef struct Neuron* NeuronPtr;
```

and then using `NeuronPtr` instead of `Neuron*` in the C wrapper? C++ Compiler shouldn't care (as long as you do a `typedef class Neuron* NeuronPtr;` in the `__cplusplus` part), but it means that it might no longer try to resolve the forward-declared struct in any C code.

Comment: yeah it, was giving the error "_Neuron_new()" when the method in C++ was called "Neuron_new" but it's not giving the error "_NeuronNew" because the method is called "NeuronNew" so the compiler must be changing it for some reason

Comment: It's totally normal for a compiler to add extra characters to the start and end of your function names (e.g. on MacOS all functions in C are prefixed with an underscore under the hood by convention), even when name-mangling for C++ is off. But I've yet to see a compiler change stuff in the middle. C++ methods do get turned into regular functions at some point, which could explain `_Neuron_new`. If Borland names the constructor differently, but `Neuron_new` was the old name you had for `NeuronNew`, maybe you're not doing a clean build? Have you tried deleting intermediate files like `.o` etc.?